# tailwindcss directives not working with style file outside of project

Tags: css, tailwind-css, postcss, monorepo

I'd like to use tailwindcss for my styles in a nx monorepo.

I made a global style `lib` with a `global-styles.scss` file to keep the global styles that should be added to every `app`.

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

.test {
   color: aqua;
}

#root {
  --teal: #008285;
  --iceberg: #D1F0F1;
  --polar: #F6FCFD;
  --scooter: #2BBEC3;
  --purple: #481059;
  --white: #FFFFFF;
  --red: #E8203A;
  --black: #2C2C2C;
}
```

in my `workspace.json` I've added the path to this style file to the build target.

```
"styles": ["apps/my-app/src/styles.scss", "libs/ui-shared/src/lib/styles/global-styles.scss"],
```

Now, both the `test` class as the css variables are picked up by my application, but none of the tailwind classes work, so the `@tailwind` directive doesn't work.

The `tailwind.config.js` and `postcss.config.js` live in the `apps/my-app` folder, and when I move the `global-styles.scss` file from the `libs` directory to this application folder, everything does work. So I wonder if there is some kind of configuration or rule that you have to keep the css files in the same (or deeper nested) location as the `postcss.config` file?

And I wonder if I can get the tailwind imports to work in that global styles file?
Thanks for the advice or explanation!

Answer (score 1):

If someone else is struggling with this, here is how I solved it:
I installed `postcss-import` as a node_module, and added this plugin to the `postcss.config.js` file in my projects that want to consume the css ui-library.

```
const { join } = require('path');
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    'postcss-import': {},
    tailwindcss: { config: join(__dirname, 'tailwind.config.js') },
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};
```

Now I can create a css file in my ui-library where I define all my common styles & where I import the tailwind classes. In my apps I can import that css file with `@import` in the app's `styles.css` file.
Purging will still work properly if you've configured your app's `tailwind.config` file as explained in the nx documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue, also using an nx monorepo. My structure looked something like this:

```
monorepo/
|-apps/
  |-my-app/
|-libs/
  |-styles/
```

I ended up fixing it by creating a `css` file in the `my-app/` directory and importing all the global styles from `libs/styles` into it. That css file was then loaded into my app. Something like:

**my-app/index.css**

```css
@import '/libs/styles/global.css`
```

You'll also need to make sure you have a `tailwind.config.js` and a `postcss.config.js` file in the root of each of your apps. If you want to keep some global rules, you can extend your tailwind config with the `presets` key. Here's what my tailwind config in `nx` looks like.

**my-app/tailwind.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: [require('../../libs/shared/styles/tailwind.base')],
  content: [
    join(
      __dirname,
      '{src,pages,components}/**/*!(*.stories|*.spec).{js, jsx, ts,tsx,html}'
    ),
    ...createGlobPatternsForDependencies(__dirname),
  ],
  plugins: [],
}
```